# Accompanist HorizontalViewPager delay in transition when swiping

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am using `HorizontalViewPager` from the Accompanist library, and one thing I've noticed is a delay in page transitions when swiping.

For some reason the page only really changes the text when you have swiped more than halfway through the next page. If you swipe less than halfway through the next page the text reverts back to its previous state. What I want is that the user immediately sees the right text state, I don't want the user to have to swipe more than halfway to see the changes.

Composable:

```
@Composable
fun TutorialPage(page: TutorialPage) {
    Column {
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {

        }

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)
        )

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 32.dp, end = 32.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    page.title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(
                        Font(R.font.manrope_medium)
                    )
                )

                Spacer(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp)
                )

                Text(
                    page.description,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(
                        Font(R.font.manrope_medium)
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.7f)
                )
            }

            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp)
            )

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun TutorialScreen(
    viewModel: TutorialScreenViewModel,
    state: TutorialScreenState
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    Column {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            HorizontalPager(
                count = state.tutorial.pages.size,
                state = pagerState
            ) {
                TutorialPage(state.tutorial.pages[pagerState.currentPage])
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            repeat(state.tutorial.pages.size) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .size(10.dp)
                        .background(if (it == pagerState.currentPage) Color.Gray else Color.LightGray)
                ) {

                }
                Spacer(
                    modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class TutorialScreenViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(
        TutorialScreenState(tutorial)
    )

    val state: State<TutorialScreenState>
        get() = _state

    private val tutorial: Tutorial
        get() =
            Tutorial.Builder()
                .addPage(
                    TutorialPage(
                        title = "Creating a project",
                        description = "Creating a project is easy! To do so, simply tap the squircle-shaped plus button at the bottom right of your home screen.",
                        image = R.drawable.tutorial_img_1
                    )
                )
                .addPage(
                    TutorialPage(
                        title = "Setting up a project",
                        description = "From then, you will see a screen in which you can input your project's name, width, and height. Confused where to start? Feel free to use some of PixaPencil's ready made quick presets or add your own for future use.",
                        image = R.drawable.tutorial_img_2
                    )
                )
                .addPage(
                    TutorialPage(
                        title = "Let's draw",
                        description = "Now, you should be navigated to your drawing screen. The screen is divided into three main sections: your current color palette, your drawing view, and your tabs.",
                        image = 0
                    )
                )
                .addPage(
                    TutorialPage(
                        title = "Tools",
                        description = "PixaPencil has a wide variety of tools to get you started, such as: pencil tool, line tool, paint bucket tool, rectangle tool, square tool, ellipse tool, circle tool, and more.",
                        image = 0
                    )
                )
                .addPage(
                    TutorialPage(
                        title = "Features",
                        description = "As well as tools, PixaPencil has a wide variety of features get you started, such as: color palette functionality, replace color, import Lospec palette, pixel perfect mode, canvas filters, brushes, and more.",
                        image = 0
                    )
                )
                .addPage(
                    TutorialPage(
                        title = "Free and open source",
                        description = "PixaPencil is 100% free (as in freedom) and open source, the code is available on GitHub for anyone to view, download, or extend. We are always open for contributors to the project.",
                        image = 0
                    )
                )
                .addPage(
                    TutorialPage(
                        title = "Join the community",
                        description = "PixaPencil has a vibrant community on Discord, which you can join here.",
                        image = 0
                    )
                )
                .build()
}
```

Tutorial:

```
class Tutorial private constructor(val pages: MutableList<TutorialPage>) {

    class Builder {
        private val pages: MutableList<TutorialPage> = mutableListOf()

        fun addPage(page: TutorialPage): Builder {
            pages.add(page)
            return this
        }

        fun build(): Tutorial {
            return Tutorial(pages)
        }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
data class TutorialPage(
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
)
```

I've tried to look online (the documentation) to find solutions, and I didn't find any nor did I find someone with the same problem with the Accompanist library.

Comment: This is because the way the pager has been implemented in accompanist. One of the thing that you can do is maybe using offset to pass the page title to the other pages. But the index of page really only changes when you really passed the halfway.

Comment: @Subfly Thanks for your reply, this is extremely disappointing. On the other hand, how would you explain then that in the official examples the behaviour was not like this? Google showed an example with images where this wasn't the behaviour as you can see here: https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/ Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Subfly it works, if you post it as an answer I will upvote it and mark it as correct solution. thanks sir.

Comment: You're welcome. Just deleted the comment and post it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using TutorialPage(state.tutorial.pages[pagerState.currentPage]) use TutorialPage(state.tutorial.pages[it]) where "it" is the builder index that pager gives you in lambda. Hope it helps :d

Comment: I am using HorizontalPager and I had the same issue that until the page is swiped at least more than half, I see my existing page as the next page. But after following @Subfly 's answer, it is working as expected.